# Quick way to build string with leading 0s for integer number?

Tags: c#

I have built a string for an integer with prefix 0s if need like this way:

```
 // myInt as input, for example: 101;
 List<string> sList = new List<string>();
 string format = "00#"; // how to build format dynamicall?
 for(int i= 1; i <= myInt; i++)
 {
     sList.Add(i.ToString(format));
 }
```

The expected result should be:

```
 001
 002
 ...
 010
 ...
 101
```

If my integer number is 10 or 1000, how can I build the format dynamically?

Answer (score 11):

How about `"#".PadLeft(desiredWidth, '0')`

You could get `desiredWidth` from `myInt.ToString().Length` - a bit grotty, but it'll work :)

In other words:

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>();
string format = "#".PadLeft(myInt.ToString().Length, '0');
for(int i= 1; i <= myInt; i++)
{
    sList.Add(i.ToString(format));
}
```

Alternatively you could skip the format string entirely:

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>();
int desiredWidth = myInt.ToString().Length;
for(int i= 1; i <= myInt; i++)
{
    sList.Add(i.ToString().PadLeft(desiredWidth, '0'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just using the [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)?

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>();
string format = string.Format("D{0}", myInt.ToString().Length);
for(int i= 1; i <= myInt; i++)
{
    sList.Add(i.ToString(format)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use log base 10 with ceil to get the digit length of a number.

```
int i = 123;
int len = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(i)));
```

Since C# can implicitly convert the int to a double, it should be reliable.  Then you can avoid the string conversion.

I've not benchmarked it against ToString() on the int, but it seems like it might be better.

Comment: But can C# implicitly convert the result of Math.Ceiling (double) to an int?

Comment: Also, it may be quicker, but how much quicker if it's called once - a couple of ticks maybe?

Comment: That's a good point.
I did just type it out here, but it would require a conversion to grab the length.

Another issue is when the largest value is 10^n (eg: 100) you will get n (eg: 2) not the 3 that would be desired in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use "00#", "000" will do the same job.

```
// myInt as input, for example: 101;
List<string> sList = new List<string>();
string format = new string('0', myInt.ToString().Length);
for(int i= 1; i <= myInt; i++)
{
    sList.Add(i.ToString(format));
}
```